# My wordpress site only shows home page, all other pages Not Found

Tags: wordpress, web-hosting

Yesterday i upload my Wordpress website on free webhost 000webhost.com through filezilla al files are successfully uploaded, database connected successfully but when i open my website www.velocitycars.site40.net it shows only homepage when i open any post or another page it goes to local host or not showing any thing it shows ( This webpage is not available) but it completely works on localhost.
plz help me
i am student this is my project
im thankful to u

Comment: Without server configuration and web page code, it'd be hard even for us to investigate the issue.

Comment: Make sure you have a .htaccess file and that it has the appropriate permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Your server configuration must be missing. Check if `.htaccess` file is there, and whether your hosting service provider supports use of them.

As a general rule of thumb, you can't hope to have perfect functionality from a "free" service provider.